# Python3 - Sorting arrays by second argument in other array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

So i have an array that looks like

```
arr = [
["some_id", 26, "some_id"],
["some_id", 93, "some_id"],
["some_id", 58, "some_id"]
]
```

and I would like the outcome to be

```
arr = [
["some_id", 26, "some_id"],
["some_id", 58, "some_id"],
["some_id", 93, "some_id"]
]
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to do so? I'm not very experienced in python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I havent tried anything because its been confusing me

Comment: Please have a look at: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3929826)!